# What is the correct PLINQ syntax to convert this foreach loop to parallel execution?

Tags: c#, parallel-processing, plinq

Update 2011-05-20 12:49AM: The foreach is still 25% faster than the parallel solution for my application.  And don't use the collection count for max parallelism, use somthing closer to the number of cores on your machine.

=

I have an IO bound task that I would like to run in parallel.  I want to apply the same operation to every file in a folder.  Internally, the operation results in a Dispatcher.Invoke that adds the computed file info to a collection on the UI thread. So, in a sense, the work result is a side effect of the method call, not a value returned directly from the method call.

This is the core loop that I want to run in parallel

```
foreach (ShellObject sf in sfcoll)
    ProcessShellObject(sf, curExeName);
```

The context for this loop is here:

```
        var curExeName = Path.GetFileName(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location);
        using (ShellFileSystemFolder sfcoll = ShellFileSystemFolder.FromFolderPath(_rootPath))
        {
            //This works, but is not parallel.
            foreach (ShellObject sf in sfcoll)
                ProcessShellObject(sf, curExeName);

            //This doesn't work.
            //My attempt at PLINQ.  This code never calls method ProcessShellObject.

            var query = from sf in sfcoll.AsParallel().WithDegreeOfParallelism(sfcoll.Count())
                        let p = ProcessShellObject(sf, curExeName)
                        select p;
        }

    private String ProcessShellObject(ShellObject sf, string curExeName)
    {
        String unusedReturnValueName = sf.ParsingName
        try
        {
            DesktopItem di = new DesktopItem(sf);
            //Up date DesktopItem stuff
            di.PropertyChanged += new PropertyChangedEventHandler(DesktopItem_PropertyChanged);
            ControlWindowHelper.MainWindow.Dispatcher.Invoke(
                (Action)(() => _desktopItemCollection.Add(di)));
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
        }
        return unusedReturnValueName ;
    }
```

Thanks for any help!

+tom

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query object created via LINQ is an IEnumerable. It gets evaluated only if you enumerate it (eg. via foreach loop):

```
        var query = from sf in sfcoll.AsParallel().WithDegreeOfParallelism(sfcoll.Count())
                    let p = ProcessShellObject(sf, curExeName)
                    select p;
        foreach(var q in query) 
        {
            // ....
        }
        // or:
        var results = query.ToArray(); // also enumerates query
```

Comment: @Tom A - what do you mean? My answer `var results = query.ToList();` didn't work? :)

Comment: @Tom A - actually it would be fair to say that Jon Skeet answered the first, also his answer is the most complete. He basically gave you 3 options: to fix your way, to use Parallel and to use Task.

Answer (score 7):

EDIT: Regarding the update to your question. I hadn't spotted that the task was IO-bound - and presumably all the files are from a single (traditional?) disk. Yes, that would go slower - because you're introducing contention in a non-parallelizable resource, forcing the disk to seek all over the place.

IO-bound tasks can still be parallelized effectively *sometimes* - but it depends on whether the resource itself is parallelizable. For example, an SSD (which has much smaller seek times) *may* completely change the characteristics you're seeing - or if you're fetching over the network from several individually-slow servers, you could be IO-bound but not on a single channel.

---

You've created a query, but never *used* it. The simplest way of forcing everything to be used with the query would be to use `Count()` or `ToList()`, or something similar. However, a *better* approach would be to use [`Parallel.ForEach`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.parallel.foreach.aspx):

```
var options = new ParallelOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = sfcoll.Count() };
Parallel.ForEach(sfcoll, options, sf => ProcessShellObject(sf, curExeName));
```

I'm not sure that setting the max degree of parallelism like that is the right approach though. It *may* work, but I'm not sure. A different way of approaching this would be to start all the operations as tasks, specifying `TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning`.

Comment: Thanks, Jon!  I awarded you the accepted answer even though you were a full minute later than the first answers, becuase you improved the answer with Paralle.l.ForEach.  ;)

Comment: @Tom: I *think* mine was actually the first answer too... it's got the lowest ID. Not that that's what acceptance should be based on though :)

Comment: Sorry, Jon, now that i compile it i get "Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'System.Threading.Tasks.ParallelOptions' because it is not a delegate type".

Comment: @Tom: check the overloads - I've probably just put the arguments in the wrong order. Try it with the lamda at the end.

Comment: Ah, i see it currently says you answered 10 mins ago and the other two were 9 mins ago, so you *were* first.  I don't see an ID number on the answers.  I guess it helps to have an extra 3 digits on one's reputation.  :)  thx again.

Comment: @Tom: I've edited my answer to correct the ForEach call (it *was* just the order of arguments) and to comment on your update. Note that using ForEach really is a lot cleaner than PLINQ here - fundamentally you're not trying to do a query, you're trying to execute something *for each* element in a collection. It's important to use the most appropriate tool for the job, rather than working around the natural focus of a particular tool, e.g. by forcing evaluation with `ToList`.

Comment: Jon: Thanks for the update. I was leaving the accepted answer as m0sa because that solution did work, and to share the crumbs of rep you leave the rest of us ;).   But your answer is now so much more complete.... i am torn....

Answer (score 1):

Should you add a line in the end

```
var results = query.ToList();
```